# How to create 2 threads first one take input numbers and the second one collect them?

Tags: c, linux

Here is my code. The sum part is not working. I need some controls for that but I couldn't do it.

I tried make number variable `number=-1`, but that also didn't work and I had an infinite loop.

By the way this is my first question that i ask here, so i can make mistakes. Sorry for that.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int number = 0, sum = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *threadFunction1()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Number:");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number == 0) break;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *threadFunction2()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (true)
    {
        sum += number;
        printf("Sum is:%d\n", sum);
        if (number == 0) break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int case1, case2;

    case1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadFunction1, NULL);
    case2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, threadFunction2, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    printf("It's over..\n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpsji.png)

Comment: Where is `sayi` defined?

Comment: You are going to need a synchronization technique (a [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)), or atomic operation) to stop these threads from reading and writing to the same memory at the same time. Otherwise, the second thread should wait to begin until the first is complete (which rather defeats the purpose of threads). That said, this code is incomplete, compiling neither as `c` or `c++`. Please choose **one** language, and provide a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: threadFunction2() runs with 'number' undefined - it will not wait for threadFunction1().

Comment: Sorry i am new here so i can't make it all right but i am going to try to fix myself. And if i talk about my question, i tried mutex but i still couldn't answer my question @Oka

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you tell us why you need the two threads in the first place? Because from the functionality you show, it seems this would be much simpler to implement just without any extra threads.

Comment: @codeling : Yes sir it is easier when i use one thread but i take system programming lesson and our professor want it that way to understand how to threads work.

Comment: @Zeze did your lesson cover thread synchronization already? As suggested by Oka above, you are going to need one of those if you have to use threads for this scenario...

Comment: @codeling Yes sir it also cover thread synchronization. I think our professor wants us to use that.

Comment: So then you should show us your attempt at using a mutex, so we can see where your mistakes were. Make sure the code is free of errors that do not pertain to the mutex. For example, your current program still has at least 2 differing errors when compiled as either C or C++, and your earlier mistake of conflating the two languages makes it unclear which you mean to use (although, I would lean towards it being C, where you forgot to include `<stdbool.h>`). Make sure you copy and paste your code **exactly** as it is into the question to avoid further mistakes.

Comment: @Oka : I edited my codes as you said. My compiler has not any errors. I also added the output.

Answer (score 2):

An immediately obvious issue is that `threadFunction1` locks the mutex

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (true)
{
    printf("Number:");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number == 0) break;
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
```

but never unlocks it. It is impossible to share a resource when one thread takes complete control over it.

The next issue is that the locking and unlocking of the mutex occurs outside of the `while` loop.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (true)
{
    sum += number;
    printf("Sum is:%d\n", sum);
    if (number == 0) break;
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

This means whichever thread gets CPU time first will lock the mutex, and enter a potentially long running loop, only unlocking the mutex when that loop ends:

If `threadFunction1` is the first to lock the mutex, this loop lasts until the user enters `0`, wherein the loop is broken and the thread is terminated. After this, `threadFunction2` never gets a turn, due to the lack of an unlock.

If `threadFunction2` is the first to lock the mutex, this loop is broken after during its first iteration, as `number` is initialized to `0`. After this the thread is terminated, and `threadFunction1` would get a turn, since the mutex is unlocked.

The final issue is that a single mutex alone is not the correct tool to use here.

Even moving the locks and unlocks *inside* the loop, so that each thread has a chance to lock the mutex, do some work, and then unlock, there is no guarantee that both threads will get equal access to the lock.

```
while (true)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    sum += number;
    printf("Sum is:%d\n", sum);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if (number == 0) break;
}
```

In fact, the opposite will probably occur. By default, it is very likely for one thread to be granted some CPU time, lock the mutex, do some work, unlock the mutex, and with its remaining time immediately lock the mutex again.

So we need a way to make two threads evenly share a resource.

One way is, instead of using a mutex, to use two semaphores to create a lockstep. This means one thread waits to for a semaphore which the other thread posts, and vice versa.

Note that in `main` we start the `to_read` semaphore with a value of `1`, meaning the `scanning` thread effectively "goes first".

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int number = 0;
static int sum = 0;
static sem_t to_read;
static sem_t to_write;

static void *scanning(void *arg) {
    while (true) {
        sem_wait(&to_read);

        printf("Enter a number: ");

        if (1 != scanf("%d", &number))
            number = 0;

        sem_post(&to_write);

        if (number == 0)
            break;
    }

    return NULL;
}

static void *adding(void *arg) {
    while (true) {
        sem_wait(&to_write);

        sum += number;
        printf("Sum is: %d\n", sum);

        sem_post(&to_read);

        if (number == 0)
            break;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    sem_init(&to_read, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&to_write, 0, 0);

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, scanning, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, adding, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    puts("It's over...");

    sem_destroy(&to_read);
    sem_destroy(&to_write);
}
```

Note that this will surely perform worse than a single threaded loop in main, doing the same amount of work, due to the overhead of context switching. That said, it is just a toy example.